# Trying to import Cropperjs gives: TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: cropperjs

Tags: cropperjs

I want to add fengyuanchen/cropperjs to an image element, but when the page loads I get this error in console `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: cropperjs`.

I am using CDN links for js and css provided on the official github page https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs

I have tried following the "Getting started" on the github page. I added CDN links, created a div with an image of an id `uploaded-img`, and then at the bottom of the page I added a script tag with the supplied code from the page

```
<script>
    import Cropper from 'cropperjs';

    const image = document.getElementById('uploaded-img');
    const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          crop(event) {
            console.log(event.detail.x);
            console.log(event.detail.y);
            console.log(event.detail.width);
            console.log(event.detail.height);
            console.log(event.detail.rotate);
            console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
            console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
          },
    });
</script>
```

I have googled this and found other people having troubles with importing, and the recommended solutions were to substitute `import Cropper from 'cropperjs';` with either `import Cropper from 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.esm.js';` or to create a var and to require it like that. Also someone suggested that I should use `"./cropperjs"` or `"../cropperjs"`. But none of the above variations worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have managed to get this working by downloading the cropper.js instead of using the CDN link, and also by copy-pasting the example modals that can be found on the official github page (https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/tree/master/examples) and modifying the code from there.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, but can't get it to work. Could you please be so kind and show me the code you used to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue
i did this:

```
git clone https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs
cd cropperjs/docs/js
cp cropper.js to my static files
cd ../css
cp cropper.css to my static files
```

and suddenly everything was working like the examples.

The files from the CDN did not work for me.